# Selenium Page down by ActionChains

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

I have a problem using function to scroll down using PageDown key via Selenium's ActionChains in python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 x64.

What I want is that my program scrolls down by PageDown twice, so it reaches bottom at the end and so I can have selected element always visible.
Tried making another function using Keys.END, but it did not work, so I assume it has something to do with ActionChains not closing or something.

**The function looks like this:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

...

```
def scrollDown(self):
    body = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
    body.click()
    ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
```

**and I use it in another file like this:**

```
mod.scrollDown()
```

The first time I use it, it does scroll down as would if PageDown key would be pressed, while another time nothing happens.
It does not matter where i call it, the second (or third...) time it does not execute.
Tried doing it manually and pressed PageDown button twice, works as expected.
Console does not return any error not does the IDE.

Comment: Do you want to scroll down to the specific element??

Comment: it is possible however to make another function clicking on another div and it would work. But that is far from elegant and cannot be reused.

Comment: No, I just want to scroll down by PageDown offset, since it is static page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe, if it has to do with the action chains, you can just do it like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

body = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Great, this seems to work. Action chains seem to load everytime when page is loaded and cannot be reused, I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to import `Keys` with `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

Comment: @J-a-n-u-s Thank you! I just come here to look for where to import this.

Answer (score 8):

I had to click on the body for the Keys.PAGE_DOWN to work but didn't need to use the action chain:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

body = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
body.click()
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#python
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just do this to scroll to the bottom.

```
#python

def scrollToBottom(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, making it simple, using the webdriver, it worked as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# open driver in a specific website
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste")

# find element of page and send PAGE_DOWN command
body = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

# it's just to see the result
time.sleep(3)
```